# What breaks if I delete the folders named Public and Sites?

Tags: macos, uti

The default home folder on Mac OS X has folders named **Public** and **Sites**.

I never use them, so what will possibly break if I delete them?

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to deleting them, you could consider hiding them in the Finder instead. To do this, launch Terminal then enter this command:

```
chflags hidden ~/Public ~/Sites
```

If you ever want to make them visible again, you would use this command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Public ~/Sites
```

Comment: This is a better solution. And you'll notice that if you try to delete them, Lion now bars you from the action. If you just don't want to see them in Finder, hide them as opposed to delete them.

Comment: Actually I made them hidden a while ago already. These folders are bothering me in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing unless you use Web Sharing, and it'll just moan at you if you switch that on.